# Counting Triangles inside of a Square

Tags: geometry

There is a $1\times 1$ unit-square with diagonals from each corner. This square contains $8$ total triangles. Now, if we expanded to an $n\times n$ square, which is comprised of these unit-squares, how many total triangles are there?

I tried to break this problem down. For a $2\times 2$ square, we have $4$ smaller unit squares, where each contain two diagonal lines. I counted the triangles by hand and found out that there are $44$ total triangles. Is there a formula for an $n\times n$ square?

Comment: Do you mean 2d triangles, or nd triangles, like pyramids in 3d?

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A100583